# Excel days since 1899-12-30 from POSIX in R

Tags: r, excel, date, lubridate, openxlsx

I have a date in POSIX in R and need to supply a data frame with it in Excel days since decimal format - which is days since 1899-12-30 and hour as a fraction of 24.

I can only find examples of the other way around.

Have had a go below, but a bit long winded and am sure there must be an existing function in lubridate or openxlsx?

```
library(lubridate)

start_date <- "1899-12-31"
  end_date <- "2022-11-15 07:00:00"
  
  d8_df <- as.character(seq(
    from=as.POSIXct(start_date, tz="UTC"),
    to=as.POSIXct(end_date, tz="UTC"),
    by="day"
  ))
  
  day_decimal <- NROW(d8_df)+hour(ymd_hms(end_date))/24
```

Comment: what about: `end_date - start_date`? or here `as.POSIXct(end_date, 'UTC') - as.POSIXct(start_date, 'UTC')` as you store it in strings.

Answer (score -1):

If you need days its `seq(0, 44883)`. In Excel 0 is 1900-01-01 and 44883 is 2022-11-18. The current day is simply days since 1900.

```r
library(openxlsx2)
dat <- data.frame(days_since_31Dec1899 = c(0, 44883))

wb <- wb_workbook() %>% 
  wb_add_worksheet() %>% wb_add_data(x = dat) %>% 
  wb_add_numfmt(dims = "A2:A3", numfmt = 22) %>% 
  wb_open()
```

Comment: Oh, hehe, came across something interesting. In Excel there is a date [29.02.1900](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/bug-1900-feb-29th-is-a-valid-date-for-ms-excel/682400e0-708e-4dd7-aa22-d72bcbd16443). Therefore we have to add 1 to every value starting from 59.

Comment: But how did you get 44883? This is the function I am after.

Comment: That's written in my answer above. It's the number of days since 1900-01-01. For instance look at the length of your d8_df object.

Comment: the d8_df object is generated by supplying the two dates. I don't know the number of days since 1900 off by heart, this is the bit I was asking for help with.